# Change imported file encoding in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, encoding, laravel-5.1

After a deep research in the forum, I am posting my problem here, because no topic matched my situation.

I am importing a file (csv or Excel) in Laravel, in my controller I am using `Input::file('file_name')` to get the file.

The user has to possibility to choose his encoding from a select in the interface.

So my problem, is that I want to change the file encoding, to that set by the user.

I used `mb_detect_encoding` function but I always if I check after, I have the ASCII encoding always...

Here my code:

```
$encoding = Input::get('encoding');
$fileContent = \File::get($importFile);
$importFile = Input::file('import_file');
$enc = mb_detect_encoding($fileContent , mb_list_encodings(), true);
if ($enc !== $encoding){
    \File::put($importFile,mb_convert_encoding(\File::get($importFile), $encoding, $enc));
}
```

Comment: Please don't edit your question so that my answer no longer makes sense.  Add new code, or new updates, as new sections.  Remember your question (and my answer) might help future visitors, it will not if it does not make sense any more.

Comment: I already said to check updates.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) for `mb_detect_encoding($str)`:

> Detects character encoding in string str

And [according to the Laravel 5.1 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#files) for file uploads:

> The object returned by the file method is an instance of the  Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile class

So in your code above, `$importFile` is an instance of a class.  Passing that into `mb_detect_encoding` won't give you the encoding of the file that instance represents.

To check the encoding of the file's *content*, you need to load that content first:

```
$importFile = Input::file('import_file');
$fileContent = file_get_contents($importFile->path());
```

Then you can pass the content to `mb_detect_encoding()` and check the encoding:

```
$enc = mb_detect_encoding($importFile, mb_list_encodings(), true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But nothing changed, I have the same problem always.. Check post update.

Comment: Can you confirm that `file_get_contents` is really working?  Eg try dumping content out, it should be a big pile of garbage if it worked.

Comment: I am working with \File::get($importFile) and if i dump the content i can see the right one.

Comment: @MoslemCherif I don't understand what you mean now ... and the edited question no longer makes sense.  Are you asking a new question?  Did my answer solve your first question? If yes, edit your question back to how it was, accept my answer, and add your new question a a separate section in your question.

Comment: the problem is not resolved, you can check the description.